# Unable to cast System.String to type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> with Session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all and thanks in advance. I have some code I'm trying to fix where I'm getting the

> error message:  Unable to cast `System.String` to type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>`

but I can't figure out which portion of the code is being interpreted as a System.String and being inserted into the session variable causing the cast to `Dictionary<string, string>` to break.

The code is fairly simple, this declaration:

```
  Dictionary<string, string> myControls; 
  private readonly string SCONTROLS = "smControls";
```

In OnInit:

```
  if(!isPostBack)
  {
      myControls = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      Session[SCONTROLS] = myControls;
  }
  else
  {
      if (Session[SCONTROLS] != null)
        {
            myControls = (Dictionary<string,string>)Session[SCONTROLS];

            if (myControls != null)
                foreach (var controlID in myControls.Keys)
                {
                    UserControl controlToAdd = new UserControl();
                    controlToAdd = (UserControl)controlToAdd.LoadControl(myControls[controlID]);
                    controlToAdd.ID = controlID;

                    formatPlaceHolder(controlToAdd);
                }
        }
  }
```

Then in a separate section where there is a control, some of the values are being updated:

```
  UserControl uc = DefaultControl as UserControl;
  if (uc != null)
    {
        uc.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        formatPlaceHolder(uc);
        if (!myControls.Keys.Contains(uc.ID))
            myControls.Add(uc.ID, uc.AppRelativeVirtualPath);
        else
            myControls[uc.ID] = uc.AppRelativeVirtualPath;

        DefaultControl.LoadNewItem(item, uc.ID, Master.EmpID.Value, ShowRemove, Master.ID);

    }
```

I have speculated that maybe part of the problem is that when `myControls` is altered it's never saved into the Session variable so when it tries to do the cast from the Session variable is basically just empty. But since it was initialized as a `Dictionary<string,string>` object to start with I would think it wouldn't matter if it were still empty?

Or is the problem that it isn't initializing properly inside the `OnInit` function?

*Updating information:*

The values in the Session variable look like this:

```
 Key: c52acd20-8d3e-44cc-bc79-8fee9c9c3064
 Value: "~/Questions.ascx"
```

Comment: Do you really have single quotes around your string,string in `(Dictionary<'string,string'>)Session[SCONTROLS];` ?

Comment: no, those are only there because without it the '<' part of the code disappears and I'm not sure how to fix that otherwise.

Comment: I have edited it out. Since you are using code blocks, you don't need single quotes.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me why the angle brackets disappear when I try to make the question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @ElaineK They are interpreted as HTML tags.

Comment: Can you assign it to a local variable and provide the string it is trying to cast? Did you accidentally clobber the dictionary somewhere else by reusing the same key?

Comment: I did search and the session variable is only used on this page in two locations that you see above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put quote around string intentionally? I think it should be,
myControls = (Dictionary)Session[SCONTROLS];